# Django's ModelForm with an HiddenInput returns invalid

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm making a small project to learn Django, and i'm having some problems trying to use hidden fields inside a ModelForm.

Theres the class:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    message     = models.CharField(max_length = 10000)
    pub_date    = models.DateTimeField()
```

And my ModelForm:

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'message', 'pub_date',)
        widgets = {
            'message' : Textarea(attrs={'cols':80, 'rows':20}),
            'pub_date' : HiddenInput(),
        }
```

This is the view:

```
def edit(request, post_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print 'VALID'
            dados = form.cleaned_data
            post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
            post.title = dados['title']
            post.message = dados['message']
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog.views.detail', args=(post.id,)))
        else:
            print 'INVALID'
    form = PostForm(instance=Post.objects.get(pk=post_id))
    return render_to_response('blog/add_post.html', {'form' : form,}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

This is the HTML generated for the form:

```
<div style='display:none'>
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' 
value='3b7c0735bf464fb4fd7dcd3011050e1c' />

</div>
<tr>
    <th><label for="id_title">title:</label></th>
    <td><input id="id_title" type="text" name="title" value="asd1111111111" maxlength="140" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><label for="id_message">message:</label></th>
    <td><textarea id="id_message" rows="20" cols="80" name="message">asd11111111111</textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="pub_date" value="2010-12-19 17:08:22.498000" id="id_pub_date" /></td>
</tr>
```

I use the same template to both create and edit posts. When i'm creating, pub_date is set in another view, and when i'm editing, I can't change pub_date on my template (thus the hidden field).
On this example, `form.is_valid()` always return False.
If I remove the `'pub_date' : HiddenInput(),` line from my form, it returns True.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the HTML of the generated page (with the hidden field)?

Comment: Ops, forgot to add it in the question. Done.

Comment: What do you see if you print 'form.errors'?

Comment: It says:
    <ul class="errorlist"><li>data_pub<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a valid dateime.</li></ul></li></ul>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the conversion from string to datetime object.

The datetime field, if no `input_formats` argument is specified, takes these formats for string->datetime conversion.

(from the docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield)

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',     # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',        # '2006-10-25 14:30'
'%Y-%m-%d',              # '2006-10-25'
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/2006 14:30:59'
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',        # '10/25/2006 14:30'
'%m/%d/%Y',              # '10/25/2006'
'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/06 14:30:59'
'%m/%d/%y %H:%M',        # '10/25/06 14:30'
'%m/%d/%y',              # '10/25/06'
```

So your value of `2010-12-19 17:08:22.498000` won't work.

The default widget for `DateTimeField` is `DateTimeInput` widget which formats the `datetime` to a string correctly, but `HiddenInput` just takes the datetime object w/ no formatting as you've shown.

If you want to use `HiddenInput` you need to `strftime` the `datetime` object to be in the correct format.

An alternative option if you just want to hide it is to not set the widget as HiddenInput but simply keep the `DateTimeInput` widget as is and hide that element with the `attrs` argument.

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'message', 'pub_date',)
        widgets = {
            'message' : Textarea(attrs={'cols':80, 'rows':20}),
            'pub_date' : DateTimeInput(attrs={'style': 'display:none;'}),
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Im that case, I'm going with the auto_now and auto_now_add solution.
If I wanted to format the time, where I should do it? I cant do in the view sinc the form gets there already invalid.

Comment: No problem! Hmm, I'm not sure how to change it in the view. I think your best bet is not using HiddenInput and let DateTimeInput handle the formatting, but if you wanted it in the view, you could try overriding the model instance's pub_date as myinstance.pub_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), but I don't know if that works or if the form makes another call to the DB

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the pub date to be the date of the post?
Is so have you tried auto_now in your models?

```
pub_date    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: I didn't know it was possible, I'm kinda new to python and django. But is this going to change when I update the post? --Forget it, I just read about auto_now__add

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to just change the widget type to SplitHiddenDateTimeWidget